# Writing a function as a composition of two functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Fix $z = x + iy$. Consider $\psi_{z}: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ defined by $\psi_z(w) = zw $. Show $\psi_{z_1z_2} = \psi_{z_1} \circ \psi_{z_2} $

Attempt: Let $\psi_{z_1}(w) = f(w) $ and $\psi_{z_2} = g(w)$. We have that $f \circ g = f(g(w)) = z_1g(w) = z_1(z_2w) = z_1 z_2 w = \psi_{z_1z_2}(w) $

is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's as simple as observing that
$$z_1(z_2w)=(z_1z_2)w
$$
isn't it?

So, yes, your analysis is correct.